# How to use windows and Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

> If  I  download  Tor  browser bundle  can  I  still  use  windows  or  chrome  browser  separately<

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Tor Browser Bundle does not interact with other browser in any way.

Unless you configure these browsers on purpose to use Tor as a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Envite's assertion that the "Tor Browser Bundle does not interact with other browser" is correct only in a superficial way. And to say that's so "in any way" in dangerously misleading.

By design, Web browsers can't access the main filesystem without instruction by users or malware. And different browsers on a computer can't share information with each other without such intervention.

However, all bets are off once a computer has been compromised by the NSA, Russian bot herders, etc. Whether the compromise occurred while using TBB or another browser, activity on all browsers (and everything else, for that matter) can be observed, logged and twisted.

Given that, mixing routine activity and TBB use on the same computer is risky. Or at least, it's risky to the degree that users expect anonymity from their TBB use. Overall, it's far safer to use Tails or Whonix, or (perhaps even better) the Tor Browser in Qubes.